# BST, change values of data of all nodes

Tags: c++, tree

How can I change the data value on all the nodes of a tree ?

My BST is made of key-value, and I want to change the value of all nodes by adding log2(total/data) where total is a known integer

What am i doing wrong here ?

I tried to use recursion for left and right side and update all at the same time but no changes were made on the tree after I print it.

```
void BST::Update(int total){
    UpdateHelper(root, total);
}


void BST::UpdateHelper(Node *&current, int total){

    if(current == NULL)     //stop if NULL
        return;

    UpdateHelper(current->getLeft(), total);
    current->setData(current->getData(), log2(total/current->getOcc()) );
    UpdateHelper(current->getRight(), total);
}
```

My Node.hpp

```
class Node{

    private:
        Node *left;                     //left child
        Node *right;                    //right child
        std::string num;
    public:
        int data;                       //number
        Node();                         //constructor
        void setData(string num, int data);         //sets number in node
        string getData();                   //return numbers from node
        int &getOcc();
        void setLeft(Node *l);          //sets left child pointer
        Node* &getLeft();                //returns left child pointer
        void setRight(Node *r);         //sets right child pointer
        Node* &getRight();               //return right child pointer
};
```

my Node.cpp

```
Node::Node(){
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
}


void Node::setData(string num, int data){
    this->num = num;
    this->data = data;
}


string Node::getData(){
    return this->num;
}

int &Node::getOcc(){
    return this->data;
}


void Node::setLeft(Node *l){
    this->left = l;
}

Node* &Node::getLeft(){
    return this->left;
}

void Node::setRight(Node *r){
    this->right = r;
}

Node* &Node::getRight(){
    return this->right;
}
```

my BST.hpp

```
class BST{

    private:
        Node * root;        //root node pointer

    public:
        BST();                                  //constructor
        ~BST();                                 //destructor
        void Insert(string num, int data);      //Inserts new number in tree
        void InsertIDF(string num, int data);      //Inserts new number in tree
        bool find(string num);                 //finds whether a number is present in tree
        void min();                             //find and print minimum number in the tree
        void max();                             //find and print maximum number in the tree
        void save_file(string filename);        //save the tree to file
        void Delete(string num);                //deletes a number from tree
        void LoadFromFile(string filename);     //loads numbers from file to tree
        void Print();                           //print tree to stdout
        void Update(int total);


        //private functions used as helper functions in the public operations
    private:
        void printHelper(Node *root);
        void UpdateHelper(Node *&root, int total);
        bool findHelper(Node *root,string num);
        void InsertHelper(Node * &current, string num, int data);
        void InsertHelperIDF(Node * &current, string num, int data);
        void findMinHelper(Node* current);
        void findMaxHelper(Node * current);
        void saveHelper(ofstream &fout, Node* current);
        Node* DeleteHelper(Node *current, string num);
        Node * findMaximum(Node * n);
        void clear(Node *currnt);
};
```

BST.cpp

```
BST::BST(){
    this->root = NULL;      //root is NULL in the start
}

BST::~BST(){
    clear(root);            //delete all nodes
}


void BST::clear(Node* current){
    if(current == NULL)
        return;

    clear(current->getLeft());          //clear left subtree
    clear(current->getRight());         //clear right subtree
    delete current;                     //delete this node
}


void BST::Insert(string num, int data){
    InsertHelper(root,num,data);   //call helper to insert
}


void BST::InsertHelper( Node * &current, string num, int data ){
    if ( current == nullptr ){
        // create new node to be inserted
        current = new Node();
        current->setData( num, data );
        current->setLeft( nullptr );
        current->setRight( nullptr );
    } else if ( num < current->getData() ){
        InsertHelper( current->getLeft(), num, data );
    } else if ( current->getData() < num ){
        InsertHelper( current->getRight(), num, data );
    } else {
        int h = current->getOcc();
        h++;
        current->setData(num, h);
    }
}


void BST::InsertIDF(string num, int data){
    InsertHelperIDF(root,num,data);   //call helper to insert
}


void BST::InsertHelperIDF( Node * &current, string num, int data){
    if ( current == nullptr ){
        // create new node to be inserted
        current = new Node();
        current->setData( num, data );
        current->setLeft( nullptr );
        current->setRight( nullptr );
    } else if ( num < current->getData() ){
        InsertHelperIDF( current->getLeft(), num, data );
    } else if ( current->getData() < num ){ 
        InsertHelperIDF( current->getRight(), num, data );
    }
}

void BST::min(){
    findMinHelper(root);
}

void BST::findMinHelper(Node* current){
    if(current == NULL)
        return;

    if(current->getLeft() == NULL)          //if no node at right
        cout<<current->getData();           //current has min data
    else
        findMinHelper(current->getLeft());  //check on left subtree
}

void BST::max(){
    findMaxHelper(root);
}

void BST::findMaxHelper(Node * current){
    if(current == NULL)
        return;

    if(current->getRight() == NULL)             //if no node at right
        cout<<current->getData();               //current node has max data
    else
        findMaxHelper(current->getRight());     //check on right subtree
}



void BST::Print(){
    printHelper(root);
}

void BST::printHelper(Node *current){
    if(current == NULL)     //stop if NULL
        return;

    printHelper(current->getLeft());        //print left tree
    cout<<current->getData() << " " << current->getOcc() << " ";        //print current node data
    printHelper(current->getRight());       //print right tree
}

void BST::Delete(string num){
    root = DeleteHelper(root,num);
}

Node* BST::DeleteHelper(Node *current, string num){
    if(current == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Node *tobeReturned;

    if (current->getData() == num) {          //if key is found

        if (current->getLeft() == NULL) {        //no node at left

            tobeReturned = current->getRight();
            delete current;
            return tobeReturned;          //right subtree should replace this node

        } else if (current->getRight() == NULL) {

            tobeReturned = current->getLeft();
            delete current;
            return tobeReturned;
        } else {

            //find maximum node in the left subtree
            Node * maxnode = findMaximum(current->getLeft());

            //copy values from max node to this node
            //      current->setData(maxnode->getData());

            //delete the max node
            current->setLeft(DeleteHelper(current->getLeft(), num));
        }
        cout<<"Deleted!!!";
    } else {        //not found
        if (num < current->getData()) {
            current->setLeft(DeleteHelper(current->getLeft(),num));
        } else {
            current->setRight(DeleteHelper(current->getRight(), num));
        }
    }
    return current;
}

Node* BST::findMaximum(Node * n){
    if(n->getRight() == NULL)       //if no node at right, current is maximum
        return n;
    return findMaximum(n->getRight());      //find in right subtree
}




void BST::Update(int total){
    UpdateHelper(root, total);
}


void BST::UpdateHelper(Node *&current, int total){

    if(current == NULL)     //stop if NULL
        return;

    UpdateHelper(current->getLeft(), total);
    current->setData(current->getData(), log2(total/current->getOcc()) );
    UpdateHelper(current->getRight(), total);
}
```

Comment: The code provided is insufficient to reproduce the problem, and has code irrelevant to the question.  Provide a [mvce], which allows us to quickly and faithfully reproduce the problem.  Help us help you.

Comment: What do `setData`, `getData` and `getOcc` do? Cna you show them? Maybe those functions have a bug.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with `UpdateHelper` except that the first param does not need to be a reference, but that's not a bug, just unnecessary.

Comment: Test your code on a small tree using a debugger. That should find the problem, whatever it is, in about five minutes. Much more efficient than posting to SO.

Comment: You do have the problem that `setData` takes an `int` for the second param but `log2` returns a `double`.

Comment: You also have the (possible) problem that you are doing integer division `total/current->getOcc()` in what seems to be a floating point calculation.

Comment: yup I guess that's my problem, so i have to make another tree ?

Comment: Maybe, but BST is a natural for a template, so you shouldn't need to duplicate all that code.